# Count the number of records group by remark

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, having

How to count the records of each remark? Each remark has a different number inside the remark column value. I need to group the records based on Remark content  but not with `cid###`. need to group by remark but each remark has some dynamic variable of cid.excluding cid number need to group it

Example - `Remarks`:

```
Remark1-cid11
Remark1-cid22
Remark1-cid33
```

Count of Group1 should be 3

Sample data

```
Remark                Id    CreatedOn                        ProcessName
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Remark1-cid22          1    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark2-cid23          2    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark3-cid24          3    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark4-cid25          4    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark1-cid26          5    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark2-cid27          6    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark3-cid28          7    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
Remark4-cid29          8    2023-12-27 18:02:54.4102746      P1
```

Desired output

```
CreatedOn  Remark   Count   Group 
-----------------------------------
2023-12-27 Remark1   2      Group1
2023-12-27 Remark2   2      Group2
2023-12-27 Remark3   2      Group3
2023-12-27 Remark4   2      Group4
```

Query I tried

```
select 
    Remark, Count (Id) 
from 
    IPocumentRequests
group by 
    Remark
having 
    Remark like '%Remark1%' 
    or Remark like '%Remark2%' 
    or Remark like '%Remark3%'  
    or Remark like '%Remark4%'
```

Output

```
Remark        (No column Name)
------------------------------
Remark1 -cid11       1
Remark2 -cid22       1
Remark3-cid33        1
Remark4-cid44        1
Remark1-cid55        1
Remark2-cid66        1
Remark3-cid77        1
Remark4-cid88        1
```

Comment: `HAVING` should **only** be used when trying to limit an **aggregated** column (`COUNT()`, `AVG()` etc.) - **not** in this case, when you're limiting directly on a column's value - this should be a group of `WHERE` clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution, I used Common Table Expression, it is faster way to work with big data.

```
WITH aa AS (
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, created_on) AS created_on,
    SUBSTRING(Remark, 1, CHARINDEX('-', Remark) - 1) AS Remark_modified,
    CASE
      WHEN Remark LIKE '%Remark1%' THEN 'group1'
      WHEN Remark LIKE '%Remark2%' THEN 'group2'
      WHEN Remark LIKE '%Remark3%' THEN 'group3'
      WHEN Remark LIKE '%Remark4%' THEN 'group4'
      ELSE Remark
    END AS Group_num
  FROM 
    your_table_name
)

SELECT 
  created_on,
  Remark_modified,
  Group_num,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
  aa
GROUP BY 
  created_on,
  Remark_modified,
  Group_num;
```

Comment: im getting error in the first line - WITH aa AS. incorrect syntax near AS

Comment: the column 'Remark' was specified multiple times for 'aa'

Comment: it is because I have specified  * (star) in beginning, it means, aa takes all columns of original table and add mutated columns, if you dont want to get it, just replace * with createdon column, it will provide more memory efficiency

Comment: regarding WITH aa AS. incorrect syntax near AS, it is not related with query, maybe you have another query in same script and it gives error for previous line, it is better to open new script and run it

Comment: im getting error - The Column 'Remark' was specified multiple times for 'aa'

Comment: yes, it was because there was multiplied mutation for same column, I edited my answer, but you need to change column names to correct column name for this query, I believe it will work for you as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256410/discussion-between-dotnetdev1-and-murad-khalilov).

Answer (score 0):

Filter the real remark out of the remark column, and group on that:

```
select  the_real_remark
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  left(remark, charindex('-', remark) - 1) as
                    the_real_remark
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        the_real_remark
```